# How ActiveModel in Rails add methods to model class by just having single line "has_secure_password" in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

In Rails (4.2.6) I can include gem 'bcrypt' in Gemfile, install it and then simply add line 'has_secure_password' in my model class.

I wonder, how it works in terms of adding methods to my model class.

If I'm looking into the source of SecurePassword on github - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb 
I see following lines

```
module ActiveModel
  module SecurePassword
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      module ClassMethods
        def has_secure_password(options = {})
        ...
          include InstanceMethodsOnActivation
        ...
        end
      ..

module InstanceMethodsOnActivation
  def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
....
```

How include call works here inside the method? How it adds instance methods to my model class? How is ClassMethods module "gets" in my model?

Is it somehow "extending" my class because I used has_secure_password call? Or it extending each model by default if corresponding gem is turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- How include call works here inside the method?

All `ActiveRecord::Base` class has a class method `:has_secure_password`

```
$ rails console
=> ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :has_secure_password
=> true
```

- How it adds instance methods to my model class?
- How is ClassMethods module "gets" in my model?

With [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) *magic*.

- Is it somehow "extending" my class because I used has_secure_password
  call?

No

- Or it extending each model by default if corresponding gem is
  turned on?

No, it's just extending your model by default.

Comment: Ok, so I actually discovered two points here. 1 - ActiveRecord [base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a26a3a075637215c9028308436ca89cba8da2ed5/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L310) class includes     ActiveModel::SecurePassword by default. So indeed has_secure_password call is available to any ActiveRecord model by default no matter if gem is included. 2. Calling this method (has_secure_password) will add instance methods to by model because of include InstanceMethodsOnActivation call. It requires and therefore validates bcrypt gem to be used.

Comment: 3. ActiveModel [spec](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword) has explicit include ActiveModel::SecurePassword for model, although it's now not needed - it's included by default for each model

Comment: That's right. `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` is an `ActiveSupport::Concern` which _extend_ class and instance of class  with some functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of understanding what anything's doing is! In this case, that would be the documentation [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) . From that, you can see that has_secure_password does this:

```
def has_secure_password
  # Load bcrypt-ruby only when has_secure_password is used.
  # This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework) being dependent on a binary library.
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
  require 'bcrypt'

  attr_reader :password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of     :password_digest

  include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

  if respond_to?(:attributes_protected_by_default)
    def self.attributes_protected_by_default
      super + ['password_digest']
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, I even looked through the sources of SecurePassword module.on github, which I provided. I couldn't get how "include InstanceMethodsOnActivation" works here. I imagine that  module ClassMethods inside of module SecurePassword gets embedded (extending) my model class (or each model class?). Therefore include call works like a class call on my model. Thus it includes methods inside InstanceMethodsOnActivation into my class. So I only need to now how has_secure_password appear to by class method of my module automatically.

Comment: This facility provide by ActiveSupport::Concern